# Form data is not getting inserted into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

Basically i have a form that when submitted it sends data to a MySQL table, the thing is of this inputs of the form is a file upload so i have to check that it really is an image.
So if i use this code right here to send it to the database:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO anuncio (anuncio_imagen, anuncio_titulo, anuncio_descripcion, anuncio_categoria, anuncio_precio, anuncio_nombre, anuncio_telefono, anuncio_email, anuncio_facebook)
VALUES ('$imagen', '$titulo', '$descripcion', '$categoria', '$precio', '$nombre', '$telefono', '$email', '$facebook')";
```

it works flawlessly, but i want to check to see if the uploaded file is an image so i separate the code above into two inserts and placed to image insert inside the image check code and left the rest of the inputed fields intact.

Here it is:

```
$imagen = ($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
$titulo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['titulo']);
$descripcion = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['descripcion']);
$categoria = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['categoria']);
$precio = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['precio']);
$nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['nombre']);
$telefono = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['telefono']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$facebook = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['facebook']);

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["photo"]["size"] < 10000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["photo"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["photo"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {

    if (file_exists("images/gallery/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["photo"]["name"] . " Ya existe en el servidor. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],
      "images/gallery/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
      $sql="INSERT INTO anuncio (anuncio_imagen)
      VALUES ('$imagen')";

    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Archivo invalido ";
}

$sql="INSERT INTO anuncio (anuncio_titulo, anuncio_descripcion, anuncio_categoria, anuncio_precio, anuncio_nombre, anuncio_telefono, anuncio_email, anuncio_facebook)
VALUES ('$titulo', '$descripcion', '$categoria', '$precio', '$nombre', '$telefono', '$email', '$facebook')";
```

But it doesn't work when i do this, the image data is not uploaded to my database, the rest of the data is uploaded but not the image data. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Get rid of the parenthesis around `($_FILES['photo']['name']);`

Comment: @JorgeGil Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of the PHP file to print the error.

Comment: You have two insert statements - Won't this produce two unconnected records in the table?

Comment: @JohnP Now that you mention it, it should right? But it doesn't, it produces a row with records of the second INSERT and nothing happens with the first.

Comment: @JorgeGil - I suspect that's because your first is erroring and you aren't seeing the error.

Comment: @JohnP I deleted the second one and left the first only, and it works. And then i deleted the first one and left the second and it works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only one `INSERT` and use `mysqli_query`. Check if the `move_uploaded_file` return is true. Try:

```
<?php
$imagen = ($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
$titulo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['titulo']);
$descripcion = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['descripcion']);
$categoria = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['categoria']);
$precio = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['precio']);
$nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['nombre']);
$telefono = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['telefono']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$facebook = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['facebook']);

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

$bol_image = false;
if ((($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["photo"]["size"] < 10000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["photo"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["photo"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {

    if (file_exists("images/gallery/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["photo"]["name"] . " Ya existe en el servidor. ";
    } else {
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],
      "images/gallery/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"])){
          $bol_image = true;
      } else{
        echo "Problem in upload the image";
      }

    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Archivo invalido ";
}

if($bol_image){
    $sql="INSERT INTO anuncio (anuncio_titulo, anuncio_descripcion, anuncio_categoria, anuncio_precio, anuncio_nombre, anuncio_telefono, anuncio_email, anuncio_facebook, anuncio_imagen)
    VALUES ('$titulo', '$descripcion', '$categoria', '$precio', '$nombre', '$telefono', '$email', '$facebook', '$imagen')";
} else{
    $sql="INSERT INTO anuncio (anuncio_titulo, anuncio_descripcion, anuncio_categoria, anuncio_precio, anuncio_nombre, anuncio_telefono, anuncio_email, anuncio_facebook)
    VALUES ('$titulo', '$descripcion', '$categoria', '$precio', '$nombre', '$telefono', '$email', '$facebook')";    
}
mysqli_query($con, $sql);

?>
```

Comment: This does works, but i want to insert '$titulo', '$descripcion', ect separately from the '$image' because you did the insert of all the fields only if the image was succesfully approved as an image, and i want to INSERT the rest of the fields even when the file uploaded isnt an image.

Comment: @JorgeGil Ok. I edited my answer. Put `if(!empty($imagen))` to verify that an image. Try again.

Comment: Works again, but it adds 2 rows to the table.

Comment: Doesn't work, aren't you checking if the file is image when $imagen is empty? shouldn't it be the oposite?

Comment: @JorgeGil No. It checks if the `$imagen` is not empty (`if (!empty($imagen))`).  If there's anything it enters. One question, if there is an image to upload, you want to edit an old record? Or you will enter all fields over the image. And when not in picture, you will only enter the field.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question, i want to enter all fields but the image into a new record, doesn't matter if there is image or not, and after that, IF there's an image to upload i want to enter it to the same record(row).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the second INSERT statement with an UPDATE statement.   The first INSERT creates the row in the table, with all the column values that you supplied there.   In the second statement, you want to UPDATE the already-created row with a new value.

Answer (score 0):

The `INSERT INTO` will only work if the record (row) doesn't already exist. If you want to do it in two steps you would use `UPDATE` on your second statement. For example:

Your code:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],
"images/gallery/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
$sql="INSERT INTO anuncio (anuncio_imagen)
VALUES ('$imagen')";
```

Instead:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],
"images/gallery/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
$sql="UPDATE anuncio
SET anuncio_imagen = ('$imagen')
WHERE anuncio_titulo = ('$titulo')";
```